# C# IEnumerable.Count() throws IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have the following scenario when grouping a collection:

```
var result = data.GroupBy(x => x.Name.Split(new char[] { '-' })[1].Trim());
```

where data variable is of type `ObservableCollection<Data>`

When I check for

```
if(result.Count()>0)
```

it throws an **IndexOutOfRangeException**

of course this happens because the string split operation throws an exception.

The question is: is there a way to check if the result of the grouping is not null and avoiding the exception?

Comment: You are splitting by `-` and accessing this array at index 1 which is the second item. Obviously there is no second item because there was no `-`. So it has nothing to do with `null`.

Comment: Yes I know, is there a way to check the length of the array inside the group by statement?

Comment: resut.Any() could do the trick ?

Comment: @KevinAvignon it throws the same exception

Comment: The problem lies with your group by. You have an IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>. Try accessing the first defaut value and invoke Any method

Comment: Something like `x => x.Name.Contains('-') ? x.Name.Split('-')[1] : ""` doesn't work?

Comment: @Andy that's a neat solution too, you should add it as an aswer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, `Enumerable.Count` just executes the deferred executed LINQ query([`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501(v=vs.110).aspx) uses deferred execution, look at the *remarks* section). So `Count` isn't to blame here.

You are splitting by `-` and accessing this array at index 1 which is the second item. Obviously there is no second item because there was no `-`. So it has nothing to do with `null`.

Maybe it is sufficient to take only those where there is a second token:

```
var result = data
.Select(x => new{ Data = x, Split = x.Name.Split(new char[] { '-' }) })
.Where(x => x.Split.Length >= 2)
.GroupBy(x => x.Split[1].Trim());
```

or the second if there is a second, otherwise the first:

```
var result = data
.Select(x => new{ Data = x, Split = x.Name.Split(new char[] { '-' }) })
.GroupBy(x => x.Split.Length >= 2 ? x.Split[1].Trim() : x.Split[0].Trim());
```

Comment: ... or even a group with a blank group name (something like)
    var result = data.GroupBy(x => (x.Name != null && x.Name.Contains('-')) ? x.Name.Split(new char[] { '-' })[1].Trim() : "");

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
var result = data.GroupBy(x => x.Name.Contains('-') ? x.Name.Split('-')[1].Trim() : "");
```

If you don't like the **?:** operator or want it less compact, use:

```
var result = data.GroupBy(x =>
{
    string name = x.Name;
    if (name.Contains('-')) return name.Split('-')[1].Trim();
    return "";
});
```

**Note:** I used `Split('-')` instead of `Split(new char[] { '-' })`

This is probably more intuitive than the solution of Tim Schmelter, but use what you want.